# Newbie AJAX Qn: request.send(information)

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I am completely new to AJAX hence this question. I want to send some information from my javascript code to my servlet.

```
function getDetails() {
    vals = document.getElementById("name").value;//works: vals does get inputted value
    request = createRequest();
    if (request == null) {
      alert("Unable to create request");
      return;
    }
    var url= "ValidateUser.do";
    request.open("POST", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = displayDetails;
    //How do I send the value of "vals" to my servlet?
    request.send("name="+vals);
}
```

When I run req.getParameter("name") on my servlet, I always get no value even though "vals" does contain the inputted value. So my question is- how do I access this value from my servlet?

**EDIT:**

```
function createRequest() {
  try {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (tryMS) {
    try {
      request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (otherMS) {
      try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (failed) {
        request = null;
      }
    }
  }
  return request;
}
```

**FURTHER EDIT:**
Servlet code: I want the println statement to print out the name.

```
//shortened: this method is called by a ControllerServlet
public Object perform(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    //retrieve customer from database
    model = SeekerCustomer.getCustomer(req.getParameter("name"));
    System.out.println(req.getParameter("name"));
}
```

Comment: Can you also add the source code for the method 'createRequest()'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function ajaxRequest(){
  var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"] //activeX versions to check for in IE
  if (window.ActiveXObject){ //Test for support for ActiveXObject in IE first (as XMLHttpRequest in IE7 is broken)
   for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
    try{
     return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
    }
    catch(e){
     //suppress error
    }
   }
  }
  else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
   return new XMLHttpRequest()
  else
   return false
 }
```

---

```
 function postReq(){
 var mypostrequest=new ajaxRequest()
 mypostrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (mypostrequest.readyState==4){
   if (mypostrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
    document.getElementById("my_Result_tag").innerHTML=mypostrequest.responseText //this is where the results will be put!
   }
   else{
    alert("An error has occured making the request")
   }
  }
 }
 var vals = document.getElementById("name").value
 var parameters="name="+vals
 mypostrequest.open("POST", "ValidateUser.do", true)
 mypostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
 mypostrequest.send(parameters)
 }
```

---

In the servlet access vals using:

```
 request.getParameter("name");
```

Comment: Its still showing null when i do System.out.println(request.getParamenter("name"));

Comment: i've added part of the Servlet code. what happens is that the ValidateUser.do is sent to the ControllerServlet, which is then directed to another servlet class and the perform method is called on this class. so this method is entered..